# jquery delete file and refesh a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

hi i am new in jquery i want to delete a file in server and do refresh in div but some error happen

image folder is ../img/tanda_tangan/tanda_tangan.png

ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hapus').click(function(){

        var imgElement_src = $('../img/tanda_tangan/tanda_tangan.png');

        // AJAX request
        $.ajax({
            url: 'removefile.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {path: imgElement_src},
            success: function(response) {             
                // Changing image source when remove
                if(response == 1){
                    $("#tanda").load(location.href + "#tanda");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and a button

```
<button type="button" id="hapus" class="hapus" >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</button>
```

removefile.php

```
<?php 
    $path = $_POST['path'];

    $return_text = 0;

    // Check file exist or not
    if( file_exists($path) ){

        // Remove file 
        //   unlink($path);

        // Set status
        $return_text = 1;
    }else{

        // Set status
        $return_text = 0;
    }

    echo $return_text;
```

and a div

```
<div id="tanda"></div>
```

what was wrong? i couldnot delete file 
in ../img/tanda_tangan/tanda_tangan.php

Comment: *"some error happen"* What is the error?

Comment: delete function not working

Comment: Could you provide the output of console? Could you provide the regarding request and response from network tab?

Comment: You have commented the code that deletes the file  ```unlink($path);``` @riyantonugroho

Comment: This is an object `var imgElement_src = $('../img/tanda_tangan/tanda_tangan.png');` not a string path, remove the JQUERY wrapper: `var imgElement_src = '../img/tanda_tangan/tanda_tangan.png';`

Comment: what is exactly the right $('#hapus').click(function(){ or $('.hapus').click(function(){ or $('hapus').click(function(){

Comment: thx mr santos you right i comented it haha

Answer (score -1):

```
var imgElement_src = $('../img/tanda_tangan/tanda_tangan.png');

// AJAX request
$.ajax({
    url: 'removefile.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {path: imgElement_src},
    success: function(response){

        // Changing image source when remove
        if(response == 1){
            $("#tanda").load(location.href + "#tanda");
        }
    }
});
```

---

I think the problem is in this line

```
var imgElement_src = $('../img/tanda_tangan/tanda_tangan.png');
```

and

```
data: {path: imgElement_src},
```

It should be a string and make sure that the path is right. the `imgElement_src` is actually a jquery object and your expecting a string of path in removefile.php

Hope it could help you out